# add number to a character to make it another character

Tags: java, ascii, letters

I want to have a char, add number to it and get another `char(a+2=c)`

```
    int leng,leng2;
    String word = "";
    String key = "";
    String enc ="";
    char x;
    char z;
    char tost;
    System.out.println("gimme word");
    word=in.next();
    System.out.println("gimme key");
    key=in.next();
    leng=word.length();
    leng2=key.length();

    for(int i=1;i<=leng;i++)
    {
        z=word.charAt(i-1);
        x=key.charAt(i-1);
        int plus=z + x;
        tost=(char)plus;
        enc=enc+tost;
        System.out.println(enc);
        System.out.println(tost);
        System.out.println((char)z);
        System.out.println((char)x);
        System.out.println(plus);
        System.out.println((char)plus);
    }
```

I want it to print `c` and in my code I do it with `charAt` because I have a full string and I tried to search for many solutions, and tried myself many things, they all didnt work sadly.

edit: full code is on, as requested 
the way of char plus doesnt work and says it is an error

Comment: Java strings are counted sequences of Unicode/UTF-16 code units, one or two of which encode a codepoint. While it makes some sense to offset a codepoint, the result isn't necessarily associated with a character. I'd guess that you want to operate on limited range like the [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) letters and wrap around if +2 is overrange.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for the whole string then you may use a for loop -

```
String r= "abc"; 
int x=2;

for(i=0; i<r.length(); i++){
  char z= r.charAt(0);  
  int plus=z+x; 
  System.out.println((char)plus);
}
```

Look at the type casting at the `System.out.println()`. Since `plus` is an `int` you have to explicitly cast it to a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You need `char plus=z+x;` not `plus=r+x;`.

That would add 2 to the character `a`, resulting in the character `c`.

You can print it with :

```
System.out.println(plus);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
String r= "abc";  
int x=2;
char z= r.charAt(0);  
plus=r+x                                       // wrong do int plus=z+x;  
String plus2=(String)String.valueOf(plus);     //not required
System.out.println(plus2);                     // plus not defined
```

Corrected Code

```
String r= "abc";  
int x=2;
char z= r.charAt(0);  
int plus=z+x;  
System.out.println((char)plus);
```

output

```
c
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ylAnax)

After your edit

change only one line

```
int plus=z + Character.getNumericValue(x);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/NECoIk)

Comment: `z=word.charAt(i-1); //z is char                                                      x=key.charAt(i-1);    //x is char                                                          plus=z + x;               //plus is int
tost=(char)plus;       // tost is char
enc=enc+tost;         //enc is String
System.out.println(enc);
System.out.println(tost);
System.out.println((char)z);
System.out.println((char)x);`       this is the original code

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't even compile. You haven't declared the variable plus. Also you want to add 2 to the character at index zero of r which is stored in z. So you'll have to add x to z. Do something like this instead

```
String r = "abc";  
int x = 2;
char z = r.charAt(0);
char plus = z + x;
System.out.println(plus);
```

Comment: `z=word.charAt(i-1); //z is char                                                      x=key.charAt(i-1);    //x is char                                                          plus=z + x;               //plus is int
tost=(char)plus;       // tost is char
enc=enc+tost;         //enc is String
System.out.println(enc);
System.out.println(tost);
System.out.println((char)z);
System.out.println((char)x);`       this is the original code