# My program is printing ascii code instead of the actual letters

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, printing

I can't believe i've gotten this far. My problem is my output. This program is suppose to take input from the user and increment each letter by 2. So after taking the String from the user I turn there message into a char array. then while outputing it I added 2 to each letter. and my ouput is acssii numbers. I need it to be the actual letter. how do I do this?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Encryption {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userMessage = " ";   
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 

    System.out.print ("Please enter your Message:");    
    userMessage = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    char arr[] = userMessage.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i< arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i] + 2);
    }

    }


}
```

Example input : "Thank you"
Example output : 867467807734918187

Please explain to me why this is happening.

Comment: If you want a "string-like" message output, you need to convert your character to a string, see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string)

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve here. if you want to map "A" to "C", "B" to "D"..etc you might want to store the mapping in a HashMap and do a lookup.

Comment: I want thank you to turn into vjcpm aqx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add number to a character to make it another character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459437/add-number-to-a-character-to-make-it-another-character)

Comment: Note: you need to consider two cases: 1) what if an input character is not a letter? (You've already given an example of that [' '].) 2) What happens when the character code for a letter plus 2 is not the character code for a letter (e.g.,  'y' + 2 and 'z' + 2)?

Answer (score 1):

You may try casting the incremented value to `char`.  Also, we can use the modulus operator to make sure that letters wrap around appropriately, e.g. `Z` should become `B`:

```
String userMessage = "ALFXYZ";
char arr[] = userMessage.toCharArray();
for (int i=0; i< arr.length;i++) {
    int nextNum = 65 + (arr[i] + 2 - 65) % 26;
    System.out.print((char)nextNum);
}
```

### Demo

Your current code, as you wrote it, is printing numbers because of the casting rules.

Comment: It should wrap around to B

Comment: @gabi145 I updated my answer to handle this edge case.

Comment: Can you explain the last two lines.

Comment: I take the letter as being character 65 (`A`) plus the 2 offset wrapped around.  Best thing would be for you to test my code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Java cannot know ahead of time that `arr[i] + 2` will be within the bounds of char (0-65535) so it will treat that expression as a number.

If you're sure the value of arr[i]+2 will never exceed this range then you can safely cast back to a char:

```
System.out.print((char)(arr[i] + 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java converts some primitive types automatically.

If *c* is a `char` and *i* is an `int`, then *c* + *i* will be treated as an `int`.

`PrintStream`, the type of `System.out`, has many overloads of `print`; the one chosen depends on the type of the argument.

Cast your addition back to `char` and it should work:

```
(char)(arr[i] + 2)
```